# CSS - Retirar foco do botão ao clicar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estou tentando tirar a borda azul que aparece no botão ao clicar, porém insiste em ficar, o que está faltando?

Obs: Estou usando o **Bootstrap 4**

Quero que não tenha foco ou estilo nas bordas do botão quando receber um clique

CSS:

```
.btn-toggle {
    height: 57px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #f8f6f6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    border-right: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    position: relative;
    left: -10px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    outline: none;
}
```

JSX:

```
<button className="btn btn-default ml-2 btn-toggle" name="btn-toggle">
```

Exemplo do problema: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Conforme você pode ver [no GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/7b5e48d30762d892f7d2781f9d5297aa8480cafa/scss/_buttons.scss#L30), o Bootstrap não utiliza  `outline` para enfatizar o estado de `:focus`. Ele utiliza o `box-shadow`.

Portanto, para remover, basta desativar essa propriedade. Assim:

```css
.btn-toggle {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Mas devo alertá-lo que ao fazer isso, os seus usuários não terão mais nenhum feedback de foco nesses elementos. Não é uma boa prática no quesito acessibilidade. Desse modo, é recomendado que você forneça outra forma de feedback para o estado `:focus`.